# Sub domain issue on Azure

Tags: azure

I need to create a sub domain as follows on Azure, how do I do that?

Mysite/jobs

I am able to create job.Mysite.azurewebsites.net. But this is **NOT** what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azurewebsite.net is not your primary domain. So azure has written code for you that create only sub domain into their DNS but you have no rights to create again sub domain in to it

Comment: Which means that I cannot create "Mysite/jobs" on Azure, correct?

Comment: yes you can not create sub domain into that you have to create sub domain into your Domain name